# Some Post Data missing after submiting the cakephp form

Tags: forms, post, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2. 
I have created a dynamic checkboxes field in view file( number of checkboxes depend on the records present on database).

When I am submitting the form and `print $this->request->data` unable to get all the checkboxes value. It display only 1000 values not more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

Problem is due to `max_input_vars` in `php.ini`. It was 1000 just increase it and able to solve my problem.